# Can I access the CruiseControl.net build label?

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

Is there any way I can have access to the CruiseControl.NET's build label number? (Maybe by using a batch file.)  Basically, I want to retrieve  the value "`LastSuccessfulIntegrationLabel`" and use in a batch file before building.

Answer (score 5):

Can't you simply use the **CCNetLabel** environment variable in your batch script (see http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Executable+Task, at the bottom)?

If you need it **before** the build, you can set your batch to run as a `<prebuild>` task: http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Project+Configuration+Block

Comment: actually Status just returns success/fail not the label as the OP asks for

Comment: In think you meant CCNetLabel, the environment variable way

Answer (score 1):

sure it is in the state file. Here is how I do it in PowerShell

```
$xml = [xml](gc $statefile)

[string]$buildnum =$xml.IntegrationResult.Label
```